Error PLS-00302: 'DBMS_PICKLER' Component Must Be Declared When Using Custom Type in Oracle
I'm encountering an issue with the DBMS_PICKLER package in Oracle. After creating a custom type
create type     NUM_ARRAY is varray(100) of NUMBER;

I'm receiving the following exception:
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 17:
PLS-00302: component 'DBMS_PICKLER' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Note that the problem occurs when I want to call a function/procedure from Java code. However, when I am calling directly from the PL/SQL console, everything seems correct.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST(P_NUMBER_LIST IN NUM_ARRAY)
    RETURN CLOB
    IS
    RESULT CLOB;
BEGIN

    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(COLUMN_VALUE) INTO RESULT FROM TABLE (P_NUMBER_LIST);

    RETURN RESULT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN RETURN NULL;
END;

SELECT TEST(NUM_ARRAY(1, 2, 3)) FROM DUAL;

Below, I am adding Java code that calls an Oracle function.
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestDaoImpl implements TestDao {
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public String test(TestRequest request) {
        var caller = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource);


        caller.withSchemaName("DIM")
                .withFunctionName("TEST")
                .declareParameters(
                        new SqlParameter("P_NUMBER_LIST", Types.ARRAY, "DIM.NUM_ARRAY"),
                        new SqlOutParameter("RESULT", Types.CLOB)
                );

        var params = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("P_NUMBER_LIST", new OracleNumberArray(request.getNumbers()));

        var clob = caller.executeFunction(Clob.class, params); // problem occurs in here
        return clobToString(clob);
    }
}


and created OracleNumberArray class for custom type:
public class OracleNumberArray extends AbstractSqlTypeValue {

    private final List<Long> values;

    public OracleNumberArray(List<Long> values) {
        this.values = isNull(values) ? List.of() : values;
    }

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public Object createTypeValue(Connection con, int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        con = con.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class);
        ArrayDescriptor desc = new ArrayDescriptor(typeName, con);
        return new ARRAY(desc, con, values.toArray(new Long[0]));
    }

}

pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.programming</groupId>
    <artifactId>problems</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>problems</name>
    <description>Solutions for Programming Problems</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem? It seems to arise when I attempt to use the DBMS_PICKLER package.
below i am adding full stack trace of an error: https://ctxt.io/2/AACoyLc2EQ

As an aside, your code can be simplified toSELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(COLUMN_VALUE) INTO RESULT FROM TABLE (P_NUMBER_LIST);.

Please can you [edit] the question and provide the EXPLAIN PLAN for the aggregation query when run from the SQL*Plus (or whichever client you are using to access the database directly) and, if possible, the EXPLAIN PLAN for the aggregation query when invoked from Java. Also details of how many numbers you are passing in via Java may be relevant (on the console it is only 3 but if you are passing 3000 from Java then a different execution plan may be used).

Possibly related? Seems unlikely but do you have any objects in your schema (or the schema Java connects to) called SYS?

@MT0 i have edited simplified code suggestion

@MT0 both from console, and from java i am sending 3 values for testing purpose.

@AlexPoole based on your answer i wrote below select, and did not get any results.
SELECT object_name, object_type FROM all_objects WHERE owner = 'DIM' AND OBJECT_NAME = 'SYS';

Is that the user you are actually connected as though? Prefixing the type name with DIM. and using withSchemaName("DIM") suggests you might be connected as a different user; and do they have a SYS object? (Either way might not be able to see it in all_objects as yourself...)

@AlexPoole Thank you for your clarification. As you mentioned, I am connected to the database using a different user, but I'm calling a function from the 'DIM' schema. There is a table named 'SYS' in the user that I'm connected to. I renamed that table to a different name, and the problem is now fixed.

@AlexPoole could you please add above comment as an answer for this question, so i could accept it as right answer

As seen in this blog post, this can happen if the user you are connected as has an object called SYS.
That causes a variation on this similar PLS-00302 error; in that case the user has an object with the same name as their own schema.
Here the object is a different schema, but because the JDBC driver is apparently calling SYS.DBMS_PICKLER.something the same kind of name clash is occurring.
The name resolution means it's seeing the current user's SYS object in preference to the schema, because of step 1a - "Search the current schema for an object whose name matches the first piece." It doesn't get to 1b (public synonynm) or 1c (schema).
It then tries to resolve the rest of the name using that SYS object - which it can't do, so it causes the error you are seeing.
To resolve this you will need to remove or change the name of your SYS object. In general, avoid having any objects which match any schema names, as well as key words, reserved words, etc.
